# Can't install Python's IMAPClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, imapclient

Trying to install [`IMAPClient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/0.9.2) using the command `pip install IMAPClient`. I'm on Windows, with Python 3.3.

It downloads fine, begins to install, then complains with `ImportError: No module named 'response_parser'`. I think that is an internal module for this library, so isn't something I can install separately.

I also tried to download the tarball manually, unpack it, and run `python setup.py install`, but get the same error.

This is a popular and stable library, so I realise I'm doing something wrong. I'm still a Python noob. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the home page](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com):

> Python versions 2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python 3 support is in the works.

It would be nicer if they updated the setup file and/or the package metadata so it could immediately give you a clear error saying "Python 3 is not yet supported" or the like, instead of a mysterious failure from the middle of the setup process. But many projects don't bother to do that, preferring to put that energy into finishing the Python 3 port instead.

---

However, if you look at [the source page](https://bitbucket.org/mjs0/imapclient):

> Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, and 3.3 are officially supported.

So, it looks like the Python 3 support is actually done, but just hasn't been pushed to PyPI yet.

Which means that, if you have mercurial installed, you should be able to do this:

```
pip-3.3 install hg+https://bitbucket.org/mjs0/imapclient
```

If you don't have mercurial (and don't want to install it), download the zipfile from the source page, unzip it, and `pip-3.3 install .` or `python3.3 setup.py install` from inside the source tree.

---

If you plan on distributing Python 3 code that requires `IMAPClient`, you may want to scan the mailing list archives (or join the mailing list and ask) to find out when it will be updated on PyPI.